# Help with context-free grammar ambiguity

Tags: computer-science, trees, context-free-grammar

- S -> aSb
- S -> aaSb
- S -> ε

Would this grammar be considered ambiguous?
I think the answer would be no, considering there is only one variable {S} and there can only be one parse tree generated.

Also, referring to the context-free grammar above, how would you draw all the possible parse trees for the string aaaabbb?
[This is all I could think of](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5F90.png)

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The language seem to be strings that contains a sequence of the empty sting and $a$ followed by $b$'s where the number of $a$s is between the number of $b$ (inclusive) and double the number of $b$s inclusive.

It's quite straight forward to show this. First when trying to reduse $a^pb^q$ where $p>2q$ we would get $a^sb^t$ where $s>2t$, $t=q-1$. Eventually we would end up in a string of only one or more $a$s. Similarily if $p<q$ reduction would always contain less $a$s than $b$ and we would end up with only one or more $b$s. And showing that we actually can reduce it otherwise we note that we always can get $t\le s\le 2t$ if $q\le p\le 2q$ and eventually we would end up with $ab$ or $aab$.

The ambiguity is in the application of the first two rules which can be chosen at will as long as there are more $a$s than $b$s (and there's more than $2$ $a$s).

So for example the string $aaabb$ can be reduced as:

$$\begin{align}
aaa\epsilon bb \\
aaaSbb && S\rightarrow \epsilon \\
aSb && S\rightarrow aaSb \\
S && S\rightarrow aSb 
\end{align}$$

or

$$\begin{align}
aaa\epsilon bb \\
aaaSbb && S\rightarrow \epsilon \\
aaSb && S\rightarrow aSb \\
S && S\rightarrow aaSb 
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Hint:
@skyking did a great job. However, I think he missed something in the first part of his answer. Take aaab as an example, it is not accepted by this language.
Since this is a problem in my assignment which is not due now, I won't post my answer.

Comment: @Lize I think I went a bit too fast there. I think I've done my homework now and updated the answer.